# Android app guide step by step

Tags: android

I am done developing my app and I want to educate the user step-by-step on how to use the app. So should I just take screenshots of the different activities, edit it on photoshop(with arrows and text saying what does what) and just introduce these images on install as activities, or is there a better more standardized way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So you need a Guided Tour for Your app.You can try Like this:

1) Make A `transparent` `Activity` over the `Activity` you want to display the Information.You can use below theme for that

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">#03afee
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

    </style>
```

2) Use `Arrows` and `Icon` for Pointing out various `Position` and there `Function`

```
Hope this could Help...
```